# Prove on the circle $z=Re^{i\theta},|e^{iz}|=e^{-R\sin{\theta}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Question :
Prove on the circle $z=Re^{i\theta},|e^{iz}|=e^{-R\,\sin{\theta}}$

My work :

$\begin{aligned}
|e^{iz}|,\quad R=1,\quad \theta=z\\
|e^{iz}|=\sqrt{\cos^2{z} +\sin^2{z}}=1
\end{aligned}
$

What now? Please give me a help...

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1508264/42969.

Answer (score 1):

For a complex number $z$ it is not true that $|e^{iz}|=1$.

Let $z=x+iy$ where $x$ and $y$ are real. Then $|e^{iz}|=|e^{ix} e^{-y}|=e^{-y}$. Now just apply this with $x=R\cos \theta, y=R\sin \theta$.

Comment: Ah thanks... actually i have the same idea, but how do i know $|e^{ix} e^{-y}|=e^{-y}$

Comment: @user516076 Since $x$ is real $|e^{ix}|=1$.

Comment: Is this something like euler's identity? Transform to $r\text{cis}(x)$ and take the modulus?

Comment: @user516076 Yes, you already wrote that in your attempt for a complex number in place of $x$. If you just restrict to real numbers  your that argument becomes correct.